# Appending HTML to component and React Component class unexpected token, expected }

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

First of all I am new to using `react`. So I have to create a React Component for appending `HTML` to `SVG` and as far as my research goes in `react` it is only possible to append `HTML`, if you create a class and method for appending to component (please correct me if I'm wrong). I created the class called `Svg` and when I try to load the script which contains the class, an error shows up telling me there is an unexpected token. At first I thought the problem was not having the plugin `transform-class-properties` so I added the data-plugins parameter to my script call and tried reloading the page and the error is still there. And I am using cdn react.

What are my questions:

- Is my method to append `HTML` to component correct?
- Why is my Svg react component class throwing an error?
- How can I resolve the error?

Script call:

```html
<script charset="utf-8"
      type="text/babel"
      data-plugins="transform-class-properties"
      data-presets="react, es2015, stage-2" 
      src="js/designer/startupMethods.jsx"
></script>
```

Script:

```
class Svg extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.displayData = [];

        this.state = {
            showdata: this.displayData,
            postVal: ""
        };

        this.appendData = this.appendData.bind(this);
        this.prependData = this.prependData.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    };

    appendData(html) {
        this.displayData.push();
        this.setState({
            showdata: this.displaydata,
            postVal: ""
        });
    }

    prependData(html) {
        this.displayData.unshift(html);
        this.setState({
            showdata: this.displayData,
            postVal: ""
        });
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let getTextAreaValue = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            postVal: getTextAreaValue
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <p>Test</p>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Svg />, document.getElementById("svg-containter"));
```

Thrown error:

```
SyntaxError: file:///C:/Users/jans/Desktop/novAMS/demo/js/designer/startupMethods.jsx: Unexpected token, expected } (11:18)
   9 | 
  10 | class Svg extends React.Component {
> 11 |     constructor() {
     |                   ^
  12 |         super();
  13 | 
  14 |         this.displayData = [];
```

Comment: I copy pasted your Svg class component in a codesandbox and it seems to work correctly. Considering that it's a syntax error you most likely spelled something wrong.

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-bardeen-nr13s

Comment: Yes at the end it was a typo error I had some other stuff in my script and after I commented it, the script worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" 
   crossorigin></script>

 <!-- Load our React component. -->
<script src="js/designer/startupMethods.jsx"></script>
```

Component Svg is ok. I checked it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grd52e

You have a link here, how to add a react to the page https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

I recommend using `React-create-app`: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started

Comment: I already have react added to my page so that is not need but thank you again for checking my code.

Comment: @Stu076 If you are creating applications, use `react-create-app` https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started. It is very helpful